# Python: Using a generator inside a while loop

Tags: python, while-loop, generator

Here's my code so far:

```
def down_data(h):
    t = 0
    while h > 0:
        t += .0001
        h = -4.9*t**2 + 1
        v = g*t
        yield h, v
    return False

def up_data(v):
    t = 0
    h = 0
    vel = v
    while h < 1:
        t += .0001
        h = -4.9*t**2 - v*t
        vel = -9.8*t - v
        yield h, vel, t
```

What I'm trying to do is get my `main()` function to output the values of `down_data(1)` for as long as that function remains valid. Running this incomplete code just sets up an infinite loop and I'm not sure why.

I'm trying to combine these two functions to simulate a bouncing ball, but stitching them together has proven difficult because of the yield function. I've tried creating a `main()` and running `while` loop over one of the functions, but this creates an infinite loop. Here's the `main()` I've tried:

```
def main():
    data = [] 
    while down_data(1):
        data.append(down_data(1))
    print(data)
```

Is there maybe an easier way to do this? The `main()` function I'm after would be something like this:

Edit: I've also tried out this, but the same problem happens; the while loop doesn't close out to move to the next `i`:

```
def main():
    data = []
    for i in down_data(1):
        while i[0] > 0:
            data.append(i[0])
            continue
    print(data)
```

Comment: `continue` returns to `while`, not to `for` - so it is useless. Maybe in last example use `if` instead of `while`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Generator functions in Python work a little different than the way you are trying to use them.

You should call `down_data(1)` only once.

Try this:

```
g = 9.8

def down_data(h):
    t = 0
    while h > 0:
        t += .0001
        h = -4.9*t**2 + 1
        v = g*t
        yield h, v

for h, v in down_data(1):
    print h, v
```

This will generate a number of output lines, but it will stop when `h` reaches 0.

Explanation: A Python function with a `yield` in it, when called, produces a generator. Each time you call `next` on the generator, the generator runs until it hits a `yield` and the yielded values are returned to the caller. If the generator hits the end of its body without yielding anything, a `StopIteration` exception is raised.

When you iterate over a generator in a `for` statement, the for-loop exits cleanly when the generator has no more data to yield.

Answer (score 3):

Ray is right that generators can be awkward to use outside of `for e in gen` which hides the StopIteration exception

but no `SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator`, at least in Python 3.5, Spyder IDE

```
g = 1

def down_data(h):
    t = 0
    while h > 0:
        t += .0001
        h = -4.9*t**2 + 1
        v = g*t
        yield h, v
    return 'fred' # this will be returned on StopIteration Exception

def mainly():
   data_gen =  down_data(1)
   data = [next(data_gen)]
   while data_gen:
       data.append(next(data_gen))
   #print(data)
   return len(data)
```

mainly() fails because of the StopIteration Exception, but the down_data(h) return does get executed following the exception:

```
 mainly()
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-103-015c95441865>", line 1, in <module>
    mainly()

  File "C:/Users/john/mypy/mySE_answers/tagd.py", line 48, in mainly
    data.append(next(data_gen))

StopIteration: fred
```

explicit try/except is needed if you are going to the end of the generator with your own next() calls

```
def my_try():
   data_gen =  down_data(1)
   try:
       data = [next(data_gen)]
       while True:
           data.append(next(data_gen))
   except: StopIteration

   return len(data), data[-1]

my_try()
Out[104]: (4518, (-0.0002038759998519435, 0.45179999999996656))
```